# Count and restrict downloads for drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Is there a way where I can keep counts on how many anonymous and authenticated users download a file in my website? The downloaded link is just hyper-linked to the file itself in the server:

sites/defaults/files/file.pdf

Thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Download Count module

you could also use the public download count module for download counts from public folders

As far as restricting the downloads, I don't think there is a module out there but you could build your own